# How to include a folder path using cmake into a C/C++ program

Tags: c++, cmake, g++, cmake-gui

My c++ program needs a folder path and I like to input from cmake configuration.
For example, my c++ program is

```
int main(){
std::string pretrained_binary_proto("/home/Softwares/Libraries/caffe-master/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel");
}
```

I like to set this folder path using cmake.

```
/home/Softwares/Libraries/caffe-master/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel
```

In my `CMakeLists.txt`, I have

```
set(CAFFE_MODEL_PATH         "/home/nyan/Softwares/Libraries/caffe-master/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel")
```

But I don't see that CAFFE_MODEL_PATH in my ccmake.. configuration.
Then how can I include that path to my program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "easy" way:

```
add_definitions(-DCAFFE_MODEL_PATH=\"${CAFFE_MODEL_PATH}\")
```

and then use `CAFFE_MODEL_PATH` constant in the code.

---

More preferred way if you have many such defines:

1. Create `yourproject-config.h.cmake` with contents like `#cmakedefine CAFFE_MODEL_PATH`.
2. Use `configure_file(yourproject-config.h.cmake yourproject-config.h)`
3. Do not forget to `include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})`
4. `#include "yourproject-config.h"` whenever and wherever you need to access your constants.

Comment: If I follow the preferred way, where to set the CAFFE_MODEL_PATH. If I do in CMakeLists.txt like option (CAFFE_MODEL_PATH "set path" "/home/nyan/Softwares/Libraries/caffe-master/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/deploy.prototxt") I can change ON/OFF only at ccmake. How can I set the the whole path at ccmake?

Comment: Don't declare it as option but `set(CAFFE_MODEL_PATH "" CACHE PATH "Path to a Caffe model")`. `option` is just a shortcut for `set` with `BOOL` type.

Comment: Step 3: `include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})`